Excel Add-in for refprop 10 not working in macOS
I want to use REFPROP 10 in my excel.
I tried the steps that was available to install the add-in into the excel.
This works in Windows but is not working in macOS.
Based on my further investigation i have found that the excel is not reading the path to the librefprop.dylib in the REFPROP.XLA add-in.
I wanted to calculate fluid properties.
When i used the wizard of the refprop it provides me with this error,
"#Make sure the REFPROP.XLA add-in is enabled to calculate items in the cells."
The ribbon is working but the main add-in is not working.
